Why does WFP trigger my callout with multiple FWP_MATCH_NOT_EQUAL conditions for FWPM_CONDITION_IP_REMOTE_ADDRESS?
I'm working with the Windows Filtering Platform (WFP) to filter traffic based on remote IP addresses. I set up my filter using the FWPM_CONDITION_IP_REMOTE_ADDRESS condition with FWP_MATCH_NOT_EQUAL to exclude specific IPs:
filter->filterCondition[0].conditionValue.uint32 = 0x614DE692 \\ (97.77.230.146)
filter->filterCondition[1].conditionValue.uint32 = 0x614DE695 \\ (97.77.230.149)

However, after adding both conditions, my callout still gets triggered when browsing from either IP. I expected traffic from these IPs to be excluded since both should match FWP_MATCH_NOT_EQUAL.
Why does WFP still trigger my callout with both FWP_MATCH_NOT_EQUAL conditions in place? How can I properly exclude multiple IP addresses using WFP?

According to the Doc:FWP_MATCH_TYPE enumeration FWP_MATCH_NOT_EQUAL Available only in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2.

How can I properly exclude multiple IP addresses using WFP in windows 10 ?

You could try to use FWP_MATCH_EQUAL instead of FWP_MATCH_NOT_EQUAL to set filters. And you could set FWP_ACTION_BLOCK to block the traffic when you create the filter.

Needs more context, preferably minimal reproducible sample. But I know how verbose that can be in this case, so at least show how you set up the callout and filter.
